# GUI based control in ROS

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to develop an application, which has a robot having multiple tasks. For example task 1 can be "move left arm", task 2 can be "move both the arms", task 3 can be "start recording from the camera" etc. I have written the code for doing all these tasks in ROS using c++ and python.

At present, I can visualize robot and camera output inside RViz. However, I want to create some GUI elements such as Buttons. Button 1 can be  "move left arm", similarly button 2 can be "move both the arms" etc.

I am not able to find out the documentation in order to add GUI elements in RViz. I am looking for suggestions and references. Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275231/gui-based-control-in-ros/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2017-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are going to need to create a custom rviz plugin. There are several [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials)

I think you'll likely want to first look at the New Dockable Panel which shows how to make a TeleopPanel as an example: http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/panel_plugin_tutorial.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-01-14**:
Thank you very much. Meanwhile, I shifted to [RQT](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt) and developed a custom plugin. It was quite easy as it was based on QT on python. I will surely check your suggestion too.